# Unsigned int representation

Tags: c++, c

```
 main() {

       unsigned int a=-9;
       printf("%d",a);//gives output -9


       cout<<a;// gives output 9429967287
       getch();

   }
```

Why it gives different output in both cases?

Do 'printf' and 'cout' treat bit pattern in a different way?

Why is 'printf' not giving the positive answer?

Comment: To elaborate on the difference in behavior: `printf()` comes from C and needs you to tell it the types of the arguments you pass (and you can lie), `operator <<()` is a magical C++ thingie that can run different code depending on the types of its operands.

Comment: Because `"%d"` implicitly converts your reference to `signed int`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `%d` does not convert anything. `%d` causes the behavior to be undefined if the argument is not of type `int`.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yes, that's expressing it much better ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you would use format specifier `%u` in printf you would get the same result as for the operator <<. Specifier `%d` in printf forces printf to interpret the corresponding argument as having type int instead of unsigned int.

In fact it is the same if you would write

```
unsigned int x = -1;
std::cout << x << std::endl;
std::cout << -1 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Using the wrong format for the type of the argument doesn't “force” `printf()` in the sense that the result would behave in any reliable way. Using the wrong format for the type of the argument is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq In fact there is no wrong format. Signed and unsigned int has the same representation except the interpretation of the signed bit. I do not see any "undefined" behaviour. The behaviour is very defined.

Comment: C99 7.24.2.1:8 does not say “The argument with the same representation as `int`”, it says “The `int` argument”. 7.24.2.1:9 does not say “If any argument is not the correct representation …”, it says “If any argument is not the correct **type** for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is **undefined**.”

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq The behaviour is well defined. The function does not know whether it is int or unsigned int. It will interpretate the object as int. As int and unsigned int have the same representation the behaviour is well defined.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq it is the same as for function defined as void f( int ) to call as f( 10u );

Comment: The behavior is undefined because the C standard says it is undefined. That is the definition of “undefined behavior”. Perhaps you can predict what it does with your compiler and with the OP's compiler, but the notion of “undefined behavior” is defined by the standard, and the standard unambiguously says that `printf("%d", -9U)` is undefined behavior. It does not matter what the function “knows” or how it “interprets” arguments. Undefined behavior is undefined behavior.

Comment: The situation is different when a non-variadic function that expects an `int` is passed as `unsigned int`. In this case, the argument is converted according to the relevant clause of the standard.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq Where did you see undefined behaviour?! You will get -9.

Comment: I saw undefined behavior in clause 7.24.2.1:9 of the C99 standard.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq And how is the argument converted?! Do you understand how unsigned int is converted to int? Describe please the conversion.:)

Comment: Here is a PDF of (a draft of) the C99 standard. You can find the definition of “conversion” and of “undefined behavior” here. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq I have the Draft. According to the standard object is region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values When referenced, an object may be interpreted as having a particular type. It is the format specifier that interpretates the object as having a particular type. As int and unsigned int have the same representation except the sign bit the behaviour is very defined: printf will consider the object as having type int.

Comment: Now go to 7.24.2.1:9 and note how it does not say anything about objects representing values. It says about **arguments being the correct type**. An argument of type `unsigned int` is not of type `int`.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq In this paragraph the Standard considers the general case. In the general case the behaviour is undefined because in the general case various data types have different sizes, allignments and internal representations and interpretatons. However in this particular case there is nothing undefined. You may write for example printf( "%u", 10 ); and printf( "%d", 10u ); The result is very defined and will be the same: you will get 10.

Comment: @Pascal Cuoq One more question: how will printf know that you use "incorrect type" unsigned int instead of int? How will printf behave?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: `printf` *doesn't* know that you've used the wrong conversion specifier for the given argument's type; that's Pascal Cuoq's point.  It's *just as undefined* as if we had used `%f` or `%s` as the conversion specifier.  Remember that all "undefined" means is that the compiler is not required to handle the situation in any particular way; it could just as easily choose to emit a diagnostic and halt translation.

Comment: @John Bode  It is very interesting how the compiler can issue a diagnostic for a function with variable number of arguments. And the comparison with for example %f is incorrect. We are considering int and unsigned int that have the same representation. In fact there is no any conversion. The memory is not changed. Only the sign bit is interpretated. 10 and 10u have the same representation. So answer please where is the undefined behaviour for an object that stores 10 or 10u. How will printf behave? It will interpretate 10 as floating number or a character array?!

Comment: -1 as many others have said this answer is wrong and you've refused to correct it even once the error was explained.

Comment: @R There is nothing wrong in the answer. The answer is totally correct. printf processes its arguments according to format specifiers.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow signed and unsigned are only guaranteed the same representation for non-negative values of the signed type. It's arguable that `printf("%d", 3u);` should work, but that argument certainly doesn't apply to `(unsigned)-9` which is out of the range of representable values for `int`.

Comment: @Matt McNabb I can not agree. In C/C++ conversion of signed to unsigned is done keeping the value. So ( unsigned )-9 will keep the value of -9.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow no, `-9` is outside the range of `unsigned` which is `0` through `UINT_MAX`.  Therefore the value cannot be kept. Also, my last comment was not referring to any conversion, it is talking about the representation of types. There is no conversion from unsigned to signed occuring if you pass a signed int to `"%u"` in printf, instead (as well as specifically being undefined behaviour) the representation of the unsigned int would be read as if it is the representation of a signed int. This is not a conversion.

Comment: Perhaps you should start a new question if you still disagree, instead of having this discussion in comments. Then someone can paste quotes from the Standard with nice formatting.

Comment: @Matt McNabb You are totally wrong. Read the Standard about how signed int are converted to unsigned integral types. It is valid conversion with well defined behaviour. The value of signed int is preserved.

Comment: @Matt McNabb You are totally wrong. Read the Standard about how signed int are converted to unsigned integral types. It is valid conversion with well defined behaviour. The value of signed int is preserved.

Comment: Yes it is valid conversion and well defined. No the value is not preserved. The value is changed from a negative number to a positive number. Unsigned int *cannot* hold a negative value. That is the meaning of the word *unsigned*. It can only hold zero or positive values.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Again you are wrong. Unsigned int can store all values of signed int. See the usual arithmetic conversion. The common type of signed int and unsigned int is unsigned int.

Comment: No it can't. C99 6.2.6.2/1 says the minimum value representable by unsigned integer types is `0`. C++ has similar text. I'm not responding any more here - comments are not for this sort of discussion. If you want to embarrass yourself further then start a new thread titled "Can unsigned ints be negative" or something.

Comment: @Vlad `Unsigned int can store all values of signed int` Are you on drugs, perchance?

Answer (score 12):

Because you told it to: `%d` is for printing an argument as a *signed* int. To print an unsigned int, you should have used `%u`.

Answer (score 6):

The `%d` format specifier to `printf` indicates that the argument is an `int`, not an `unsigned int`. So `printf` thinks `a` is an `int`, which is why it prints out a negative value.